# Application.Capturescreenshot(fileName) save to specific path

Tags: unity-game-engine, screenshot

i am using in my unity project this method that saves the camera viewport to the file system:

```
Application.Capturescreenshot(fileName)
```

it is work great but i want it to be saved under a specific path.
for example : `Application.Capturescreenshot(c:/screenshots/filename);`
how can i managed this?
thnaks!

Comment: It would be trivial to copy the file after you save the snapshot in local folders in C#. However, note that when you deploy your app/game, there might not be such folders as "C:/...", as in Android/iOS, the C:/... does not exist, and this is valid only for Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the absolute file path easily by passing it as a string. In your case, using this statement should work just fine:

```
Application.CaptureScreenshot("C:/screenshots/filename");
```

Note that it will give you an error if *screeshots* folder does not exist. Hence, if you are uncertain of that, you could modify the code accordingly:

```
// File path
string folderPath = "C:/screenshots/";
string fileName = "filename";

// Create the folder beforehand if not exists
if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

// Capture and store the screenshot
Application.CaptureScreenshot(folderPath + fileName);
```

Lastly, if you want to use a relative path instead of an absolute one, Unity provides [dataPath](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html) and [persistentDataPath](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) variables to access the data folder path of the project. So, if you want to store the screenshots inside the data folder, you could change the *folderPath* above accordingly:

```
string folderPath = Application.dataPath + "/screenshots/";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        var nameScreenshot = "Screenshot_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy-hh-mm-ss") + ".png";
        ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(nameScreenshot);
```

Try this !

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question